# "Connection closed before full header was received" and IP gets blocked

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a problem with API call, when I call API on Postman everything works fine but when I call API with Flutter HTTP sometimes I got error "connection closed before full header was received" and then IP is blocked from server for my device and I cannot use the app any more. After almost 1 hour it gets resolved and IP gets restored and then I can use the app again.
I read all threads about it on SO and GitHub but none of the solutions worked for me
Note: this error happens only sometimes not every time.